# C++ - Is there a way to only parse lua with lua library without executing it?

Tags: c++, parsing, lua

The question speaks for itself. Let's say I want to create an editor for lua with syntax highlighting and code hinting. To do this I need to continuously parse the code and apply proper rules. How can I do this with Lua library?

Comment: I don't think lua library will be of any help here. Its primary purpose is to load and execute lua code. So it does not provide an API for something like AST extraction.

Comment: run the Lua compiler?

Comment: You might be interested by following the [language server protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/).

Comment: @Jarod42 I'll take a look at it. Seems like it's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

See [lua_load](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_load)

> Loads a Lua chunk without running it. If there are no errors, lua_load
> pushes the compiled chunk as a Lua function on top of the stack.
> Otherwise, it pushes an error message.

Alternatively:

To find Lua errors run your code through the [Lua compiler](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/luac.html).

To find anything else run the code through a linter like [luacheck](https://github.com/luarocks/luacheck) or implement your own.

Parse the output of both to display warnings and errors.